# How does perf unwind the stack in newer kernel versions with ORC?

Tags: linux-kernel, stack-trace, perf

I'm running perf on a kernel `5.4.80` and explicitly use `fp` call graph:

```sh
perf record -g --call-graph fp ...
```

When running `perf script` it can profile the stack trace without any problem. This is while the kernel is not compiled with frame pointer enabled, rather with ORC:

```sh
CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y
# CONFIG_UNWINDER_FRAME_POINTER is not set
```

The result is that the kernel symbols are available in `/proc/kallsyms`.

On the other hand, seems `perf-script` only knows about `fp`, `dwarf` and `lbr`: [source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.80/source/tools/perf/util/callchain.c#L270).

I am wondering how perf script is able to unwind the stack and generate the report despite recording with `fp` call graph option on a kernel with `ORC` stack unwinding enabled?

Comment: According to https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/unwinding-stack-frame-pointers-and-orc, ORC is basically the same metadata as DWARF's `.eh_frame`, but maybe stored differently.  It's possible that `dwarf` could work if `perf` knows where to look for the relevant metadata.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I know that ORC is simplified version of dwarf, but the `--call-graph` passed to perf is `fp`. Does this mean that regardless, perf ignores the passed option and uses orc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [perf-record(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html),

```
--call-graph
           Setup and enable call-graph (stack chain/backtrace)
           recording, implies -g. Default is "fp" (for user space).

               The unwinding method used for kernel space is dependent on the
               unwinder used by the active kernel configuration, i.e
               CONFIG_UNWINDER_FRAME_POINTER (fp) or CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC (orc)

               Any option specified here controls the method used for user space.
```

So, `--call-graph` only controls how the call-graph is unwound in userspace. In kernel space, whichever unwinder is actively enabled is used.